# Xubuntu 22.04.4 Slow desktop start after login (2-15 minutes)

Tags: xubuntu, login, lightdm

I have problem and I need help with my Dell Inspiron 3525.

The PC starts up correctly until the login screen. After entering my username and password and accessing it, I can see the wallpaper and the mouse without anything else, not even my own wallpaper but that of Xubuntu. The mouse cursor shows the idle icon without loading anything, and it stays like this for between 2 and 15 minutes doing nothing. In most cases, it takes 2 minutes until the wallpaper is set and the desktop loads. I should note that I am using Xubuntu. I am not sure what could be causing this, so here are the logs from various commands to see if they can help.

systemd-analyze critical-chain

```
The time when unit became active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @5.545s
└─multi-user.target @5.544s
  └─docker.service @1.373s +4.171s
    └─containerd.service @1.196s +174ms
      └─network.target @1.194s
        └─NetworkManager.service @1.107s +85ms
          └─dbus.service @1.104s
            └─basic.target @1.079s
              └─sockets.target @1.079s
                └─snapd.socket @1.077s +1ms
                  └─sysinit.target @1.069s
                    └─systemd-backlight@backlight:amdgpu_bl0.service @4.541s +5ms
                      └─system-systemd\x2dbacklight.slice @4.503s
                        └─system.slice @204ms
                          └─-.slice @204ms
```

systemd-analyze blame
https://pastebin.com/5J08NBV2

sudo cat /var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log
https://pastebin.com/PbCt6sKi

**cat .xsession-errors**

https://pastebin.com/KmWYJFaN

I noticed that the delay can be observed in the journalctl -b 0 --no-pager, as I opened a tty while the desktop was loading with Ctrl+Alt+F3 and could see that the delay is logged between 10:40:55 and 10:42:59, which is when the desktop seems to start loading

https://pastebin.com/5K0BtYVw

can you help me?
thanks!

Comment: I would look in *Settings -> Session and Startup -> Application Autostart* for anything that might be out of the ordinary, or start disabling start up apps from there until you eliminate what might be holding up after the login.  Or also look at the Advanced tab of the Session and Starup and maybe try disabling the GNOME or KDE compatibility services.

Comment: Thanks terrance, I disabled all applications at start and that fixed the delay, idk what application was but its enough for me :D

Comment: This worked for a while, but when I connected the monitor through HDMI and the battery, it slowed down again and took 2 minutes. Now, I have all the startup programs disabled and with everything disconnected, it doesn't go back to being fast. That is, Terrance's solution only worked for a short time before the issue returned.

Comment: Sounds like it might be a bad HDMI cable.  If you leave the HDMI cable unplugged does it speed back up?  I did have an issue with a satellite system where the HDMI cable caused the system to be extremely slow or not even come up at all.  The stuff I suggested was only to help troubleshoot and not meant to be an answer.

Comment: Do you have the HDD or SSD model? If it's the HDD model, then it might just be slow loading a bunch of files